# Execute interval through Spring Boot JPA + Postgresql + H2

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I am trying to create a JPA Repository Query in Spring Boot.

- I am using spring-data-jpa 2.1.5, spring-boot 2.1.3, postgresql driver 42.2.5, h2database 1.4.200, Java 1.8

My conditions are :

- I have to use PostgreSQL for production and H2 for unit (integration) tests.
- I should not use native query (postgres x h2).
- I need to get customer records from customer's table
- But only the Customers that registered at least 24 hours before the current date.
- So I mean DB date. I cannot use Java to pass any parameter into the query.

My customer Entity looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "cust_no")
   private int custNo;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   @Column(name = "registration_timestamp")
   private Date registrationTimeStamp;
}
```

And my customer repository will be like:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

   @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.registrationTimeStamp <= SOMETHING")
   List<Customer> getCustomers24HoursAfterRegistration();

}
```

I really don't know what should I put that place refers SOMETHING. I think I can use something like CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - SOMETHING_REFERS_24_HOURS.
All the examples are about the nativeQuery. Or passing parameter from Java. I can't use INTERVAL because Spring JPA doesnt support.

I can not believe that such a simple process is not in Spring JPA which supports both two RDBMS (PostgreSql and H2). And I want to ask is there any way to do that?

Comment: I think you can use a string with the date. The best way to know is to try the query in your db or write a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t wanna you native query then you have to use Query methods

you can do something like

```
 List<User> findByCreatedAtGreaterThanEqual(Data createdAt);
```

For more, you can see ( https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods )